# Proof Perspective Projection is not Affine

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projection-matrices, geometric-transformation

So I've been trying to understand why projective transformation isn't an affine transformation nor linear. I know because it doesn't preserve parallel lines, but how does one prove it mathematically using the concept of affine transformation that it is indeed not an affine nor linear transformation?

Comment: For the subject of linear transformation, show that it fails additivity or homogeneity. I.e, $T : V \rightarrow W$ being a map between vector spaces $V,W$, show that for any two vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{V},$ it holds that $T(u) + T(v) = T(u+v)$ and for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is any field agreeing with $V,W$, $\lambda T(u) = T(\lambda u).$

Comment: [Affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Definition) and [Collineation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation) might be a good resource.